# Creating accessors in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a class and create accessors in Eclipse that I will have to use later on, however I'm having trouble doing so. I have the directions listed below but keep getting stuck on the last two.

Directions:

> Write a class `StringSet`.  A `StringSet` object is given a series of `String` objects.  It stores these Strings (or a reference to them, to be precise) and can perform limited calculations on the entire series.  A `StringSet` class has the following specification:
>
> 1. a single instance variable of type `ArrayList<String>`
> 2. a single default constructor
> 3. mutator that adds a String newStr to the `StringSet` object
>
>    `void add(String newStr)`
> 4. accessor that returns the number of String objects that have   been added to this `StringSet` object
>
>    `int size()`
> 5. accessor that returns the total number of characters in all    of the Strings that have been added to this `StringSet` object
>
>    `int numChars()`
> 6. accessor that returns the number of Strings in the `StringSet`   object that have exactly `len` characters
>
>    `int countStrings(int len)`

My code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StringSet {

    ArrayList<String> StringSet = new ArrayList<String>();

    public StringSet() {
    }

    public void add(String newStr) {
        StringSet.add(newStr);
    }

    public int getsize() {
        return StringSet.size();
    }

    public int getnumChars() {
        return StringSet.length();
    }

    public int countStrings(int len) {
        if (StringSet.equals(len)) {
            return StringSet.size();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My advice to you is to learn the Java coding standards and decide on a rigorous format that you follow religiously.  Your code doesn't read well.  Lack of care in naming, standards, and formatting usually means poor coding skills as well.  This is clearly a homework assignment.  Do one method at a time and test each one.  Don't type in a bunch of stuff and wonder why none of it works.  I'd refer you to JUnit and test driven development.  You'll thank me someday.

Comment: Can you mention what is the erroe you got and what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Hey thanks, its saying its undefined for the type ArrayList<String>. Yea its  definitely a homework assignment, and we just dived into coding without going over any standard format, but thanks for the advice.

Comment: First mistake: `ArrayList<String> StringSet = new ArrayList<String>();` Use proper Java naming conventions and start with a lower-case letter. Second, try not to name variables after class names or reserved words, because it is confusing and can cause compile-time errors. **Tip:** Accessors are also called "getters". These methods, in Java, are usually prefixed with 'get'. So, if you have an instance variable called `list` then your accessor will be named `getList()`. This method will return the same type as the variable it is returning. See [JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans)

Answer (score 2):

Your string set is an array of string objects. Think of it as though you've added each of the following to `stringSet` (indexes are to the left of the value).

```
0[Hello]
1[My]
2[name]
3[is]
5[Keith]
```

For simplicity I'm going to use a primitive `String[]` rather than an `ArrayList`

### Question 5

Create a variable that will increment its value by the size of *each* String. Then use a `for` loop to evaluate each individual `String`'s length and add it to that variable:

```
int totalCharsInStringSet = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stringSet.size(); i++) { // loop through each index
    // add the length of the string at this index to your running tally
    totalCharsInStringSet += stringSet[i].length; 
}
// you've read through all of the array; return the result
return totalCharsInStringSet;
```

### Question 6

Calling `stringSet.size()` is just going to count how many elements are in the array; i.e., 5. So you need to create a tally of how many individual strings match the target length. Craete a variable to keep that tally. And again, use a for loop to iterate through the array, and compare each string's length to the target value. If it matches, increment your tally:

```
int numberOfMatches = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < stringSet.size(); i++) {
   if (string[i].length == len) {  // "len" is your input target length
        numberOfMatches ++;
   }
}
return numMatches;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, helped me a ton!

Comment: Sure. Just make sure you really focus on understanding what each line is doing. Often it can help to simply write out in terse, plain English statements exactly what you hope to achieve at each line of code. Translating that into Java is then the easy part.

Answer (score 0):

Number 5: You iterate through your `ArrayList` and add up the length of the strings stored there.
Number 6: You iterate through you `ArrayList` and check if the length of the String matches the desired length, and keep track of the number of matching strings.

Answer (score 0):

Well ArrayLists don't have a length() method, so what you need to do to count total number of chars in the string set is iterate through the StringSet list and find the length of each string and add it to a running total.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < StringSet.size(); i++){
   sum = sum + StringSet.get(i).length();
}
return sum;
```

For the countStrings you need to place this if statement in a for loop and increment a sum each time the if statement is triggered and return the sum

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < StringSet.size(); i++){
    if(StringSet.get(i).length() == len){
        sum = sum + 1;
    }
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Question 5:

```
public int getnumChars()
{
    int countChar = 0;
    for(String strSet: StringSet){
        countChar += strSet.length();
    }
    return countChar;
}
```

For Question 6:

```
public int countStrings(int len)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(String strSet: StringSet){
        if(strSet.length() == len){
            count++;
        };
    }

    return count;
    }
```